# How Come Right Clicking Doesn't Work?

Tags: touchpad, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 dual-booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04...to be honest I don't know why you need to know this lol. Anyway, whenever I use other Operating Systems Right-clicking on the touch pad of my Dell Inspiron laptop works but whenever I use Ubuntu it doesn't work it registers pretty much as a left click, now I have another mouse for my laptop so it's not an issue because right clicking works on this. I'm just curious because Linux isn't the problem of my laptop on this issue, it's specifically Ubuntu. I could run Mint and everything would run properly unfortunately I don't like Mint as much as Ubuntu. I'm mostly curious as to why it doesn't work and I apologize for dragging on with this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link describes the steps I took on my Dell Inspiron to cure the "no right click" issue:  [Fix NO Right Click error](https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/)

```
Summary:
  - install Gnome Tweak
  - Run Gnome Tweak, 
  - select "Keyboard & Mouse"
  - In "Mouse Click Emulation" section, select "Area"
```